# How to reliably check an object is an EcmaScript 6 Map/Set?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, collections, set, ecmascript-6

I just want to check that an object is a `Map` or `Set` and not an `Array`.

to check an Array I'm using lodash's `_.isArray`.

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  if (_.isArray(arg)) {
    // doSomethingWithArray(arg)
  }

  if (isMap(arg)) {
    // doSomethingWithMap(arg)
  }

  if (isSet(arg)) {
    // doSomethingWithSet(arg)
  }
}
```

If I were to implement `isMap`/`isSet`, what does it need to look like? I'd like for it to be able to catch subclasses of `Map`/`Set` if possible as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The situation is similar to pre-ES5 methods to detect arrays properly and reliably. See [this great article](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) for the possible pitfalls of implementing `isArray`.

We can use

- `obj.constructor == Map`/`Set`, but that doesn't work on subclass instances (and can easily be deceived)
- `obj instanceof Map`/`Set`, but that still doesn't work across realms (and can be deceived by prototype mangling)
- `obj[Symbol.toStringTag] == "Map"`/`"Set"`, but that can trivially be deceived again.

To be really sure, we'd need to test whether an object has a `[[MapData]]`/`[[SetData]]` internal slot. Which is not so easily accessible - it's internal. We can use a hack, though:

```
function isMap(o) {
    try {
        Map.prototype.has.call(o); // throws if o is not an object or has no [[MapData]]
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
function isSet(o) {
    try {
        Set.prototype.has.call(o); // throws if o is not an object or has no [[SetData]]
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For common use, I'd recommend `instanceof` - it's simple, understandable, performant, and works for most reasonable cases. Or you go for duck typing right away and only check whether the object has `has`/`get`/`set`/`delete`/`add`/`delete` methods.

Comment: Why not use `Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == '[object Set]'`? Is there some case when that would fail, other than someone overriding `Object.prototype.toString`? (I don't think an overridden `Object.prototype.toString` is worth worrying about - it's a bad practice that would break lots of existing libraries.)

Comment: @MattBrowne `Object.prototype.toString` is equivalent to using the `Symbol.toStringTag` method - you don't need to overwrite the global, it can be messed with on a per-object basis.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
function isSet(candidate) {
  return candidate instanceof Set;
}
```

If the candidate object has `Set.prototype` in its prototype chain, then the `instanceof` operator returns `true`.

*edit* — while the `instanceof` thing will work *most* of the time, there are situations in which it won't, as described in Bergi's answer.

Comment: Will that work even if the set is a subclass of `Set`? I should've specified, that as a concern.

Comment: @nackjicholson well that depends on how you're creating the subclass. The `instanceof` operator returns `true` if the `.prototype` of the constructor is in the object's prototype chain.

Comment: @nackjicholson: As long as you do `class MySet extends Set`, yes.

Comment: Note that if you're writing code for a library that will be redistributed, it would be good to check first if `window.Set` is defined (unless your library includes a shim for older browsers). (Or to make it work on the server too, you could check `typeof Set != 'undefined'`).

Comment: @MattBrowne yes in fact I myself found bugs involving `instanceof` when dealing with object passed between `<iframe>` environments! I'll update this answer (which is recent enough to be embarrassing).

Comment: Cool. I'm updating my open-source `deepCopy()` function and thinking I should use `Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == '[object Set]'`. I just commented about using `Object.prototype.toString` on Bergi's answer...

Comment: @MattBrowne it's regrettable that whoever drove getting `Array.isArray()` into the spec didn't also get `Set.isSet()` etc in there also.

Comment: Yes. Actually it's worse in this case because unlike arrays, Sets are only in the most recent spec. It's common to use a shim for older browsers, and I just realized that the `Object.prototype.toString` check wouldn't work for those. I may post an answer here with what I ultimately land on.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
export function isMap(item) {
  return !!item && Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === '[object Map]';
}

export function isSet(item) {
  return !!item && Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === '[object Set]';
}
```

Unless the prototype of this method was overridden

Comment: Is the boolean check strictly needed? Seems to work with falsy values without.

Comment: Yes it's needed because object.toString is called on item if it's undefined or null it will throw error

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox, for `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` I get `"[object Null]"` and "[objectUndefined]" for a call on `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is used in Vue source code. You can borrow the idea from here.

```js
export const isMap = (val: unknown): val is Map<any, any> =>
  toTypeString(val) === '[object Map]'
export const isSet = (val: unknown): val is Set<any> =>
  toTypeString(val) === '[object Set]'


export const objectToString = Object.prototype.toString
export const toTypeString = (value: unknown): string =>
  objectToString.call(value)
```

It is easy to understand. After converting the object to string. Then you just need to check the value of string if it is **'[object Map]'** or **'[object Set]'**

I highly recommend front-ender read the **Utility functions** in the source code. You can always find the best practice.

Here is the link to Vue source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/packages/shared/src/index.ts

you can find the code I quoted here.

Answer (score 0):

Or check the prototypes:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(i) === Map.prototype
```