# Javascript How can I tell if an object is a Map Iterator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a some NodeJS code that is being passed a Map Iterator.  What is the correct way to examine a Javascript object to determine that it is a "Map Iterator"?

I've tried:

```
typeof myMap.keys() returns 'Object'
typeof myMap.keys().next === 'function' returns true
```

So I'm checking to see if the object being passed has a next() function.  Is there a better way to do this?

The Chrome debugger the object is a Map Iterator, so I'm guessing there is a more correct Javascript way to do this.

Comment: Does this feet what you want?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries

Comment: what does `Object.prototype.toString.call(myMap.keys())` output?

Comment: `instanceof` can do the work. Just check if `myMap instanceof Map` . Incase this is true, `myMap.keys()` will be a MapIterator

Comment: @Prasanna, I like this as the answer.  Do you want to answer this and I'll select your response as the answer?

Comment: Why exactly do you care about this? Every iterator that yields key-value-tuples should work for your function!

Comment: @Bergi, I was writing a utility function Util.myTypeof(obj) where obj could be anything in Javascript.  I found the Map Iterator wasn't being handled correctly by myTypeof() so I asked this question so I could fix it.

Comment: @PatS How was it handled, could you post your code? How did you expect it to be handled (and why)? Notice that JS uses mostly duck typing, so trying to distinguish objects of different kinds is usually futile.

Comment: @Bergi, The code was basically 
`mysort(obj, comparator){ if (Util.myTypeof(obj) === 'map-iterator') { return Array.from(obj).sort(comparator); } . . . `.  I expect to return a sorted array and be able to handle Array, Object returns property names of direct object, Map returns keys in map, Set returns keys in set.  I asked this because when I passed a Map Iterator the code wasn't handling it correctly.  I think I understand your point about Javascript typing.  If there is a better solution please post one.  Thanks.

Comment: @PatS Sounds like you really wanted `(Array.isArray(obj) ? obj : obj instanceof Set ? Array.from(obj) : obj instanceof Map ? Array.from(obj.keys()) : Object.keys(obj)).sort(comparator)`. Yes, you should not pass a map entries iterator if you expect the keys - either pass the map itself and distinguish it [as that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926193/1048572) or pass the `map.keys()` iterator.

Comment: @Bergi, lol.  That's it in one line. :-)  Thanks for your interest in helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is check if it's a Map (which can be iterated over), you can do that with `myMap instanceof Map`, which returns a boolean.

Comment: A `Map` is something different than a `MapIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You you get the `Symbol.toStringTag` property of the object

```js
var m = new Map;
m.set(1, [123]);
var gen = m.entries();

console.log(gen.toString()); // "[object Map Iterator]";
console.log(gen[Symbol.toStringTag] === "Map Iterator"); // true
```