# how to use 'getOwnPropertyNames' to iterate through contents of a map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, properties, es6-map

I have the map posted below in the code section. I added some values to the map as shown.But when i tried to display the contents of the map using 
'getOwnPropertyNames' as shown in th code, the log statement in the loop does not display any thing.

please let me know how to utilize 'getOwnPropertyNames' properly

**code**:

```
const mymap = new Map();

const mapKeyToValue = (key, value) => {
  mymap.set(key, value);
};

const getMyMap = () => mymap;

mapKeyToValue('1', [{ 'a': 10, 'b': 100, 'c': 1000 }]);
mapKeyToValue('2', [{ 'a': 20, 'b': 200, 'c': 2000 }]);
mapKeyToValue('3', [{ 'a': 30, 'b': 300, 'c': 3000 }]);
mapKeyToValue('4', [{ 'a': 40, 'b': 400, 'c': 4000 }]);


console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mymap));//displays []

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mymap).forEach( (v) => {
  console.log(mymap[v]);//displays nothing
});
```

Comment: What is your goal in using `getOwnPropertyNames` ?

Comment: @ChrisR actually, in another code i have a map or it could be an array, and i donot have any knowledge about key it comprise..so i decided to make a test to learn how can i iterate through keys in a map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map does not have properties (which would be limited to string and symbol keys). It stores its elements on the inside. To iterate through a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), use its `entries`, `values`, `keys`, or implicit iterator methods with a `for … of` loop:

```
for (const [key, value] of mymap) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: so, getOwnPropertyNames should be only used with arrays?

Comment: Uh, `getOwnPropertyNames` should not even be used with arrays. Arrays are iterated with standard `for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` or `for (const val of arr)` syntax.

Comment: would you please tell me, which data structure i should use getOwnPropertyNames with?

Comment: @LetsamrIt It's meant as a reflection method for arbitrary objects (mostly those where `for … in` doesn't fit because of enumerability), not necessarily for something used as a data structure.

Comment: @ChrisR It's not a prototype method

Comment: Wooooops, my bad, indeed. Link to the doc, so we're clear => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: thanx..but is there any way in javascript to determine if the object in hand is an array or a map??

Comment: @LetsamrIt Sure, `Array.isArray(x)` and `x instanceof Map` ([or worse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926193/1048572)) will do. In general you should design your code so that you know which type a variable has, though.